# $p=2^k+1$ is prime $>3$ iff $3^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv {-1} \pmod p$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> If $p \in \mathbb N$ and there is $1<k \in \mathbb N$ such as $p=2^k+1$. Then $p$ is prime iff $$3^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv {-1} \pmod p$$

I know that there is $l \in\mathbb N$ such as $k=2^l$ and then $\frac{p-1}{2} = \frac{2^k+1-1}{2}=\frac{2^{2^l}}{2}=2^{2^{l}-1}$

Answer (score 3):

If $p=2^k+1$ is prime, since $p\equiv (-1)^k+1\pmod3$, $k$ must be even. Thus, $p\equiv 2\pmod 3$. Moreover, we know $p=2^k+1\equiv 1\pmod 4$. Thus $3^{\frac{p-1}2}\equiv \left(\frac3p\right)\equiv (-1)^{\frac{p-1}2}\left(\frac p3\right)\equiv-1\pmod p$ (here $\left(\frac3p\right)$ is the Legendre symbol).

Now let $p=2^k+1$ be such that $3^{\frac{p-1}2}\equiv-1\pmod p$. Furthermore let $p$ have a prime factor $q$. Then $3^{2^{k-1}}\equiv -1\pmod q$. Thus $3$ has order $2^k$, so that $2^k|q-1$. However, $q\le p$, so we mut have $q=p$.

Comment: I believe you might need to modify the argument a bit for the converse part as $$3^{2^k}\equiv1 \mod q \implies \text{order of } 3 \text{ divides } 2^k$$

Comment: If the order of $3$ is $< 2^k$, it must divide $2^{k-1}$. But this is impossible since $3^{2^{k-1}}\equiv-1$. This is essentially the place where I use that $p-1$ is a power of $2$.

Comment: my bad I didn't get it at first. thanks, @KentaS for helping me out